# How to rerender multiple datatables with typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using typescript in angular 7, I want to have two data tables in one page, and I want a rerender method for each one so I can use a search bar, I know data tables already have a search bar, but I need to assign the data arrays in each search because the data's have thousand of rows that make the data tables ultra slow, so with a search I filter the array making it faster.

I already know how to rerender if I have one table, using dtElement, dtInstance.destroy(); and dtTrigger.next(); but I can't make it work using two tables. I found this code in a forum but gives me this error, and I don't know what to do because I'm not using JQuery: DataTables warning: table id=tablaClaveProdServ - Cannot reinitialize DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3

This is table 1

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Busque una clave del catalogo SAT" (change)="buscarClaveProdServ()" [(ngModel)]="busquedaClaveProdServ">         
<div class="table-responsive table-wrapper-scroll-y">
    <table id="tablaClaveProdServ" datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions['new']" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger['new']" class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Clave</th>
                <th scope="col">Descripción</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>   
            <tr class="pointer" *ngFor="let dato of listaClaveProdServ;">
                <td scope="col">{{dato.clave}}</td>
                <td scope="col">{{dato.descripcion}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

This is table 2 (almost same table, changes the data array)

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Busque una clave del catalogo SAT" (change)="buscarClaveUnidades()" [(ngModel)]="busquedaClaveUnidad">     
<div class="table-responsive table-wrapper-scroll-y">
    <table id="tablaClaveUnidad" datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions['new']" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger['new']" class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Clave</th>
                <th scope="col">Descripción</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>   
            <tr class="pointer" *ngFor="let dato of listaClaveUnidades;">
                <td scope="col">{{dato.clave}}</td>
                <td scope="col">{{dato.descripcion}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

This is my typescript file

```
export class FrmCatRegistroProductoComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy, OnInit {

  //data arrays
  listaClaveProdServ: Array<GenericModel>;
  listaClaveUnidad: Array<GenericModel>;

  //words to search
  busquedaClaveProdServ:string;
  busquedaClaveUnidad:string;

  @ViewChildren(DataTableDirective)
  dtElements: QueryList<DataTableDirective>;
  dtOptions: DataTables.Settings[] = [];
  dtTrigger: Subject<any>[] = [];

  constructor(
    private listas: GenericList) {
  }    

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dtTrigger["new"] = new Subject<any>();
    this.dtOptions['new'] = {
      pagingType: 'full_numbers',
      language: this.listas.dtEspanol,
      searching: false
    };
    this.listaClaveProdServ = [];
    this.listaClaveUnidad = [];
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
      this.dtTrigger['new'].next();    
  }
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
      this.dtTrigger['new'].unsubscribe();    
  }
  rerender():void{
    this.dtElements.forEach((dtElement: DataTableDirective) => {
      dtElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => {
        dtInstance.destroy();
        this.dtTrigger['new'].next();    
      });
    });
  }

  //the search methods
  buscarClaveProdServ():void{
    this.listaClaveProdServ = this.listas.ClaveProductoServicio.filter(o => o.descripcion.includes(this.busquedaClaveProdServ));
    this.rerender();
  }
  buscarClaveUnidades():void{
    this.listaClaveUnidad = this.listas.ClaveUnidad.filter(o => o.descripcion.includes(this.busquedaClaveUnidad));
    this.rerender();
  }
}
```

I also tried sourrounded dtTrigger with setTimeout(()=>{...}); unsuccessfully.

Hope someone can help me, very thanks if you read this far.

Answer (score 4):

I define separate triggers on each table:

```
<table #table1 datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger1">...

<table #table2 datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger2">...
```

Then rerender like so:

```
  dtTrigger1: Subject<any> = new Subject();
  dtTrigger2: Subject<any> = new Subject();

  rerender(): void {     
    this.dtElements.forEach((dtElement: DataTableDirective) => {
      if(dtElement.dtInstance)
        dtElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => {
          dtInstance.destroy();          
      });
    });
    this.dtTrigger1.next(); 
    this.dtTrigger2.next();    
  }
```

Profit!

Answer (score 1):

By adding `destroy:true` in `datatable options` has solved my problem.
Inside your `ngOnInit()`

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dtTrigger["new"] = new Subject<any>();
    this.dtOptions['new'] = {
      pagingType: 'full_numbers',
      language: this.listas.dtEspanol,
      searching: false,
      destroy:true //Add to allow the datatable to destroy
    };
    this.listaClaveProdServ = [];
    this.listaClaveUnidad = [];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also having the same issue. And then I found this answer [Here in GitHub](https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/issues/1088#issuecomment-329900012)

As per [l-lin](https://github.com/l-lin)

> You need to use `@ViewChildren` instead of `@ViewChild`:

Sample Code

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, OnInit, ViewChildren, QueryList } from '@angular/core';
import { DataTableDirective } from 'angular-datatables';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-rerender',
  templateUrl: 'rerender.component.html'
})
export class RerenderComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChildren(DataTableDirective)
  dtElements: QueryList<DataTableDirective>;

  // ...

  rerender(): void {
    this.dtElements.forEach((dtElement: DataTableDirective) => {
      dtElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => {
        // Do your stuff
      });
    });
  }
}
```